# Get name from input text '_ is my name' Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to get a word at the beginning of the statement 'is my name'. I would preferably use regex to solve this. I currently have:

```
word = '((.*) is my name'
name = re.search(word,userInput)
group = 2
print("Your name is", name.group(group))
```

When I use regex online it say this should be in group 2, however an example output is: "Your name is word is my name". Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `userInput`?

Comment: Any text that has _ is my name. Such as "word is my name"

Comment: You have an unmatched open parenthesis `(` - this code should raise an error as-is.

Comment: I apologize! Fixed the error. It should work now

Answer (score 0):

I think a look ahead regex will do the job for this nicely:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('.+(?= is my name)')
print(re.search(pattern, 'Alex is my name'))
```

OUT:

`Alex`

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed out by @esqew, you have an unmatched parenthesis at the beginning of your regex, so if you remove it, you'll only have one group:

```
import sys
import re

userInput = input()
word = '(.*) is my name'
name = re.search(word,userInput)
group = 1
print("Your name is", name.group(group))
```

The output for `Joe is my name` is:

```
Your name is Joe
```

Notice that group 1 matches every character before   `is my name`, so that for `Joe Smith is my name`, the result is:

```
Joe Smith is my name
```

Finally, consider the look ahead regexp from @osint_alex answer since it doesn't have to deal with groups.